# MacOS app bundle compiled from qt, icon on and off

Tags: macos, qt

I have been annoyed by this problem for a long time.

Firstly I compiled an executable by qt-5.8.0 in qt-creator.

Then I manually built .app directory MyApp.app, by the operations introduced on the Internet, I successfully built an app without any icon.

Then I built the .icns file and put it under Resources directory and manually set up Info.plist file under the Contents directory, Info.plist file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
</dict>
```

And then when I put the .app file into some directories, it displays the icon properly, but when I move it to other certain directories it fails, say ~/Desktop.

I am really confused by the problem, and I haven't use Xcode during the whole process.

Thanks for any advice!